# c# n-tier solution web service client to service layer strange behaviour

Tags: c#, exception, endpoint, webservice-client, n-tier-architecture

I am creating my first n-tier solution in c#.
I've created my tiers, including a service tier just for practicing (it's not neccessary)

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and for back end db I use SQL express ver 14.

So I have created a web service client in my main app referencing to the web service of service layer.

Everything is working ok, until I restart VS or just reload the application.
Then, I have to "Update Service Reference" on my main app to make it work.
Otherwise, I am having an exception :

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 'There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:52132/Srv.svc that could accept the
>   message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.'
>
> Inner exception 1 : *WebException: Unable to connect to the remote
>   server*
>
> Inner exception 2 : *SocketException: No connection could be made
>   because thetarget machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:52132*

The update works every time, no hesitation, (service reference address at http://localhost:52132/Srv.svc ) and then everything works ok.

Cleaning/Rebuilding in ether debug or release mode have no result at all.

The other thing I noticed is that this has been done once or twice during runtime.
Suddenly same exception, same procedure to revive the connection.

No changes made to web sercvice soever.

My app.config setting :

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:52132/Srv.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISrv"
            contract="DataService.ISrv"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISrv" />
</client>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you hosting your wcf service project on local IIS or IIS express? (Right click your WCF project > Properties > Web tab > Servers section). Flip this to local IIS and configure it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to have an answer...
I've spend some hours searching. No luck.
Publishing the serivice to IIS though, makes the problem go away.
This is a bit frustrating when developping because every time you make a change to the serivice you have to publish the service again to keep the uninterrupted functionality.